# openshift 3.11 install fails - Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d",

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I'm trying to install Openshift 3.11 on a one master, one worker node setup.

The installation fails, and I can see in `journalctl -r`:

```
2730 kubelet.go:2101] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
2730 cni.go:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
```

Things I've tried:

1. reboot master node
2. Ensure that `hostname` is the same as `hostname -f` on all nodes
3. Disable IP forwarding on master node as described on https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/7967#issuecomment-405196238 and https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux
4. Applying kube-flannel, on master node as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54779881/265119
5. `unset http_proxy https_proxy` on master node as described on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54918#issuecomment-385162637
6. modify `/etc/resolve.conf` to have `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, as described on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48798#issuecomment-452172710
7. created a file /etc/cni/net.d/80-openshift-network.conf with content `{ "cniVersion": "0.2.0", "name": "openshift-sdn", "type": "openshift-sdn" }`, as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743756/265119

The last step does appear to have allowed the master node to become ready, however the ansible openshift installer still fails with `Control plane pods didn't come up`.

For a more detailed description of the problem see https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/11874

Comment: whats your architecture? arm or amd?

Comment: Not entirely sure. The hardware is managed by vmware. And I've installed Openshift on the same hardware previously without issue.

Comment: have you tried another CNI eg. weavenet. If there are issues like that its good to test another CNI to proof its not an unknown incompatibility

Comment: No, I havent tried another CNI. I've installed OpenShift 3.11 before, and never needed to.

Comment: That error can be a red herring as it will be thrown when _other_ issues are present. Are the static pods for the control plane components coming up? Run ```docker ps -a``` on the master hosts. You can find the logs for the static pods in ```/var/log/containers```. Usually the issue is with the master api pod not coming up and the rest of the pods failing due to that. I would suggest walking carefully through the [installation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/index.html) section of the official documentation and making sure everything is order - firewalls/dns/lbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was using a too recent version of Ansible.

Downgrading to Ansible 2.6 fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? What did Ansible do that caused this?

Comment: Its not so much that Ansible caused this, its that the openshift-ansible project requires Ansible 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Along with Step 6:
make sure that hostname and hostname -f bot return the FQDN for your hosts.

https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/10798

Comment: Yes, `hostname` and `hostname -f` are the same.